# Debug Remote Java Application using VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Eclipse, we have possibility to set debug configuration for remote Java application.
I have attached the same in image.
How can same be achieved in VS code [image]using Community Server Connector extension?

Answer (score 1):

To attach to a remote debugging session for a Java project

1. Open the project in VSCode and select the folder containing the source
2. Click on the **Run** menu then select **Open Configurations** or **Add Configuration...**, if you use the Add method, select **Java: Attach to remote program** and it will put the lines below in for you
3. Add the remote server details

   ```
   {
       "version": "0.2.0",
       "configurations": [
           {
               "type": "java",
               "name": "[Name for debug session]",
               "request": "attach",
               "hostName": "[Remote Host Address]",
               "port": [Debug Port],
           }
       ]
   }
   ```
4. Click on **Run** and select **Start Debugging**

Edit: This JSON is held in the **[project root]/.vscode/launch.json** file

Edit: If you have multiple configuration, then hit Ctrl + Shift + P and select **Debug: Select and Start Debugging** and select the configuration (the value you put in the Name field) that you want to use.